# European and American decimal format for thousands

Tags: r, csv, number-formatting

I'm reading a csv and I have a problem with American and European numerical formats. American have `.` for decimals and European for thousands. This is the reading csv routine.

```
read.csv("data.csv",header=F,skip=4, sep=";", fileEncoding= "cp1252")
```

The thing is when I have a number finished with 0, without decimals.

```
> 2.100 
[1] 2.1
```

Imagine also:

```
> 2.113
[1] 2.113
```

I substituted, `.` for blank and I have an European number, but in the other case I have 21.

Also I tried some changes, but i have some digits with `,` and I tried to use decimal and it didn't work.

EDIT:

What arrive at df.

```
2.100   21.882,30
```

gsub("\.", "", number);
gsub("\,", ".", number);

I make some transformations, after:

```
2.100   21882.30
```

R thinks it's a 2,1 but it was a 2100, the read.csv2 doesn't work.

Comment: `read.csv` is for American-style CSV files. `read.csv2` is for European-style CSV files. It will probably solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `dec` to specify which symbol you want for the decimal place. For example, if the decimal sign is `.`:

```
read.csv("data.csv",header=F,skip=4, sep=";", fileEncoding= "cp1252",  dec = ".")
```